# How do you zoom out a web page automatically?

Tags: html

I have built a calculator with JavaScript, but am having trouble displaying it on mobile. By default the page is zoomed in slightly. If the user manually zooms out, the calculator displays perfectly (it fits perfectly on the screen). Is their a way to zoom out by default??

You  can visit my calculator here:
http://hntr.atwebpages.com/calculator/calculator.html

Comment: Please add some code to inspect. The issue probably lies within your CSS

Comment: ...please go to the link provided and have a look at the source.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. If you want a question to get serious answers, you need to attach the relevant part of your code. It's not anyone's job to go through your code and debug it.

Comment: :(    What part of the CSS code would you like to see?

Comment: I already pointed you to the CSS part, which provides instructions to the browser regarding the elements' dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the zoom in many browsers by accessing the `zoom` property as follows:

```
document.body.style.zoom = value + "%";
```

Where value is some number. For example, this would set the zoom to 50%:

```
document.body.style.zoom = "50%";
```

You might have to play around with different ways of calculating the zoom value though. Also note that this doesn't work in all browsers, but seems to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

well as I can see your website Is built in the hardcode It doesn't contain any responsive design You should use framework Like Bootstrap or Bulma